# Parse log files for relevant data from multiple lines

Tags: c#, winforms, parsing, logfile

C#, Winforms:
I have a log file I need to parse. This file contains transactions requests from a program, but the program writes the transaction across multiple lines.

I need to get the ID# and if the request was processed or denied for whatever reason. The problem is that these requests are on multiple lines. My only saving grace is that they contain the same time stamp from the logger. The (##) is not usable since it is a temporary placeholder, thus (19) may repeat multiple times throughout the log.

I was thinking of scanning for a PR_Request, substringing the ID# and the time stamp, but I dont know how to make a streamreader move down to the next 4 lines and write it out to be one single line in a file.

Examples:

`06/10/16 08:09:33.031 (1) PR_Request: IID=caa23b14,
06/10/16 08:09:33.031 (1) PR_Mon: IID=caa23b14,
06/10/16 08:09:33.031 (1) RESUME|BEGIN
06/10/16 08:09:33.031 (1) RESUME_TRIG|SC-TI`

`06/10/16 08:19:04.384 (19) PR_Request: IID=90dg01b,
06/10/16 08:19:04.384 (19) PR_Mon: IID=90dg01b,
06/10/16 08:19:04.384 (19) RESUME|DENIED: Access not granted.`

I need output to be in a single line for a file. That way, I can just parse it with another program and feed the data into a database.

`06/10/16 08:09:33.031 PR_Request: IID=caa23b14 | RESUME | BEGIN | RESUME_TRIG | SC-TI
06/10/16 08:19:04.384 PR_Request: IID=90dg01b | RESUME | DENIED: Access not granted.`

EDIT:

Okay I think I have a base code here. It works, kind of. It takes such a long time because I had to open another file streamer when it found a match to PR_Request, then scan the file again with the same fullstamp (date + process number). It will then look for RESUME|BEGIN or RESUME|DENIED and then write out that it succeeded or failed.

Is there any way to perhaps speed this up by getting the streamreader line where it originally found the PR_Request, have it start on another line, count maybe to 5 more lines, then stop it? This would help speed up the program considerably.

```
        string inputfolder = inputloctxt.Text;
        string outputfolder = saveloctxt.Text;
        string outputfile = @"ParsedFile.txt";

        try
        {
            string[] readfromdir = Directory.GetFiles(outputfolder);
            foreach (string readnow in readfromdir)
            {
                using (StreamReader fileread = new StreamReader(readnow))
                {
                    string fileisreading;
                    while ((fileisreading = fileread.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (fileisreading.Contains("PR_Request"))
                        {
                            string resumed = null;
                            string fullstamp = fileisreading.Substring(1, 26);
                            string datestamp = fileisreading.Substring(1, 21);
                            string requesttype = fileisreading.Substring(27, 22);
                            string iidnum = fileisreading.Substring(53, 8);
                            using (StreamReader grabnext01 = new StreamReader(readnow))
                            {
                                string grabnow01;
                                while ((grabnow01 = grabnext01.ReadLine()) != null)
                                {
                                    if (grabnow01.Contains(fullstamp))
                                    {
                                        if (grabnow01.Contains("RESUME|BEGIN"))
                                        {
                                            resumed = "TRUE";
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        else if (grabnow01.Contains("RESUME|DENIED"))
                                        {
                                            resumed = "FALSE";
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            File.AppendAllText(outputfolder + outputfile, 
                               datestamp + " " + requesttype + " " + iidnum + " " + resumed + Environment.NewLine);
                            resumed = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Searching for `PR_Request` seems ok to identify beginning, the question is how will you find the end (it's not clear from given input data)? Then (if you know where it ends) it shouldn't be the problem to go through lines from beginning to end, removing anything before "`) `" and outputting what is left (probably removing `,` at the end if any too, replacing `:` with `|` and all such small things). In any case consider to add your attempted solution and specify what is the problem. Because I don't really see it.

Comment: @Sinatr The log portion ends on a new timestamp from what I can tell. The program in question seems to log it with date-time-placeholder-triggered event.
That triggered event then spits out what it did on multiple lines. The problem is those new lines do not contain the ID# in reference, so I cant just easily grab everything with the same ID. I need to have my program scan the file, find a PR_Request, get the ID#, then go down 1 or 2 lines to see what actually happened (was it denied, did it go through, etc).
I can match the timestamps, i dont know how to index those lines using streamreader

Comment: It isn't really possible to answer this without more detailed knoledge about what the log file can contain. What is the number in brackets, is it a thread ID? Under what circumstances can it be reused?

Comment: @MartinBrown I updated the question with the code I have. I know it is very basic, and its just opening a stream reader, but I am not really sure what to do once the program begins scanning. easymoney202 stated to use a regex, so I am going to try and work with that. Although it will take time to research how to put it in the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you need to use **Regular Expressions**.  There is a namespace *System.Text.RegularExpressions* you can use and reference the capture groups that I made for you in the example.

Use these sites for reference:

- https://regex101.com/
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx

I started off the Regex for you, it is not pretty but it should get the job done.

```
(?:\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3}\s\(\d+\)\s)(PR_Request: IID=[^,\n]+)(?:\,\n\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3}\s\(\d+\)\sPR_Mon: IID=[^,\n]*\,\n\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3}\s\(\d+\)\s)((RESUME|BEGIN|\||DENIED: Access not granted.)*)(?:\n\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3}\s\(\d+\)\s)*((RESUME_TRIG|SC\-TI|\|)*)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try to use a reg expression. I do not fully know what this does so it may take me some time to reply with results so I can dissect this information.

Comment: If you put the example I made into the regex101 link, it helps explain what it does

Comment: Yes sir! I see what it did. I see that it finds everything I have requested, but is there a way to then parse it into a single line? If you look at my edited example of my code, I have something that does kind of what I want, but it's extremely slow. I like your method since it finds everything at once, but I am a bit unclear on how to implement it. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Replaced the carriage returns (\r\n) with line breaks (\n)
`var txt = @"<INSERT TEXT HERE>".Replace("\r\n", "\n");
            Regex r = new Regex(@"<INSERT REGEX HERE>");
                var matches = r.Matches(txt);
                for (int a = 0; a < matches.Count; a++)
                {
                    var match = matches[a];
                    for (int b = 0; b < match.Groups.Count; b++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Match{0}|Group{1}:{2}", a, b, match.Groups[b].Value);
                    }
            }`

Comment: Did this help you?  If so please mark as answer, if not, please let me know what else you need help with